# ytick descriptions in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to make a heatmap a heatmap with extensive y axis descriptions.
[image]

I would like to know if there is anyways to have a second and a third layer on the y tick labels.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,25))

sns.set(style="darkgrid")


colName = [r'A', r'B', r'C', r'D', r'E']
colTitile = 'Test'
rowName = [r'a', r'b', r'c', r'd']
rowsName = [r'Vegetables', r'Fruits', r'Meats', r'Cheese',
            r'Candy', r'Other']
rowTitile = 'Groups'

heatmapdata= np.arange(100).reshape(24,5)

sns.heatmap(heatmapdata,
            cmap = 'turbo',
            cbar = True,
            vmin=0,
            vmax=100,
            ax=ax,
            xticklabels = colName,
            yticklabels = rowName) 

for x in np.arange(0,len(ax.get_yticks()),4):
    ax.axhline(x, color = 'white', lw=2)
```

Is there any way to do this? Which function should I use?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The labels for the rows can be set up in the graph settings, but other than that, I think the annotation function is the only way to handle this. the second level group names are set using the annotation function, and the coordinate criteria are set using the axis criteria. Axis labels are added using the text function with axis criteria.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
sns.set(style="darkgrid")

colName = [r'A', r'B', r'C', r'D', r'E']
colTitile = 'Test'
rowName = [r'a', r'b', r'c', r'd']
rowsName = [r'Vegetables', r'Fruits', r'Meats', r'Cheese',
            r'Candy', r'Other']
rowTitle = 'Groups'

heatmapdata= np.arange(120).reshape(24,5)

sns.heatmap(heatmapdata,
            cmap='turbo',
            cbar=True,
            vmin=0,
            vmax=100,
            ax=ax,
            xticklabels=colName,
            yticklabels=np.tile(rowName, 6)) 

for x in np.arange(0,ax.get_ylim()[0],4):
    ax.axhline(x, color = 'white', lw=2)

for idx,g in enumerate(rowsName[::-1]):
    ax.annotate(g, xy=(-100, idx*90+45), xycoords='axes points', size=14)
ax.text(x=-0.3, y=0.5, s=rowTitle, ha='center', transform=ax.transAxes, rotation=90, font=dict(size=16))
plt.show()
```

[image]